Why is getchar() hanging despite poll() returning a "good" value?
I am making a text editor in C, and using the poll() function to determine if an input is ready (if not, it continues with other functionalities not shown in this example. Then, if a character is available (i.e. the if (!poll(...)) condition being false), it is collected with getchar() and processed. Here is the code:
#include <poll.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {

        input_set_tty_raw();
        
        char input_history[1000];
        int curr = 0;
        struct pollfd in = {.fd = 0, .events = POLLIN};
        
        while (1) {
                if (!poll(&in, 1, 20)) {  // arbitrary timeout for poll function
                        continue;
                }
                char c = getchar();

                /* problem code */
                if (input_history[curr - 1] == '\033' && c == '[') {
                        while (poll(&in, 1, 0)) {
                                getchar();
                        }
                        return input_restore_tty();
                }

                // handle inputs
                input_history[curr++] = c;
        }

        return input_restore_tty();
}

In case you are wondering, the input_set_tty_raw() is equivalent to running $ stty raw, allowing for pure (or raw) handling of inputs, character by character. The input_restore_tty function returns the terminal back to the original state.
A problem arises with special "escape sequences" that are passed into stdin when keys such as the arrow keys are pressed. For example, when pressing an arrow key, a sequence of bytes 27-91-6x are passed in. You can use this small utility to check out this behavior:
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
        input_set_tty_raw();
        while (1) {
                char c = getchar();
                if (c == 'q') {
                        return input_restore_tty();
                }
                printf("%d\n\r", c);
        }
}

The aforementioned 27-91-6x behavior seems to share the 27-91 header (which is a "\033[") with other escape sequences, such as hitting the delete (not backspace) key on a keyboard entering 27-91-51-126.
Therefore, in the second conditional labeled problem code, I check if the previous character entered was this \033 escape character and if the current character is the 91 (or [) character. If so, I let all the other inputs pass using the while statement.
From testing, it seems like the delay between the \033 and the [ is non-zero, while the remainder of characters in the escape sequence seem to be entered instantly, hence the inner poll having a timeout of 0. I have put a return statement inside the conditional to show exactly when all the inputs are handled.
However, this code seems to hang. Compiling and running this, you can see that the code does not return when you press an arrow key, as expected. However, it returns when you press another key after that, indicating that the program is hanging in the getchar() function inside the problem code block.
To my knowledge, poll() only returned a non-zero value when there was input available. So, why is it hanging, and how can I fix this?
If needed, the helper functions are below, with their required include.
#include <termios.h>

static struct termios tbufsave;
int input_set_tty_raw(void) {
        struct termios tbuf;
        if (tcgetattr(0, &tbufsave) == -1) {
                return 1;
        }

        tbuf = tbufsave;
        tbuf.c_iflag &= ~(INLCR | ICRNL | ISTRIP | IXON | BRKINT);
        tbuf.c_oflag &= ~OPOST;
        tbuf.c_lflag &= ~(ICANON | ISIG | ECHO);
        tbuf.c_cc[VMIN] = 1;
        tbuf.c_cc[VTIME] = 0;

        return tcsetattr(0, TCSANOW, &tbuf) == -1;   // 1 for error
}

int input_restore_tty(void) {
        return tcsetattr(0, TCSANOW, &tbufsave) == -1;   // 1 for error
}


First, getchar() returns int, not char.  Stuffing the returned value into a char mean you either can not detect EOF or you will confuse legitimate input with EOF.  And you seem to be ignoring the fact that you're running poll() against fd 0 while getchar() reads from the stdin stream, which is likely buffered.

The input_set_tty_raw() function is equivalent to stty raw in the terminal, which I believe unbuffers stdin

Additionally, I'm making a text editor similar to vim, so EOF doesn't really matter to me

Yes, using input_set_tty_raw() means that the terminal driver returns characters immediately, but you also need to let the standard I/O package know that it should not buffer characters, or use read() rather than standard I/O to collect the data.

Replacing getchar() with read() has the same outcome. It hangs until I press another key, which then prompts a return.

Nevermind... replacing both getchar() calls with read() (where in the previous comment I had just done the one) somehow fixes the issue. Thank you for your help, feel free to leave this as an answer!

@vs07 so EOF doesn't really matter to me Until you get a bug report that your editor hangs when the input is closed for any reason...

Well, correct me if I'm wrong, but vim seems to treat EOF (ctrl-d) as an editor command and scrolls down a page, so it doesn't seem to care that much either

Redirect the input of vim from a file — it detects EOF when it finishes reading the file.

Transferring a comment into an answer.
Yes, using input_set_tty_raw() means that the terminal driver returns characters immediately, but you also need to let the standard I/O package know that it should not buffer characters.  You would probably do this using setvbuf().
Alternatively, use read() rather than standard I/O to collect the data.

just a note for anyone coming across this, the thing that fixed the problem was changing the getchar() calls to read() calls. i haven't tried setvbuf() yet

I should have said "I've not tried messing with setvbuf()", though the "probably" alludes to that possibility.  Using read() is certainly the way I'd go.
